# How do you fetch Multilist Field values in Web Forms user control?

Tags: sitecore-api

I am trying to access multilist field values in Visual studio ascx page using `<asp:Repeater>` web control. But i am not able to fetch the values from Sitecore. Which Sitecore webcontrol should we use to fetch multilist field values in repeater?

```
<sc:Image Field="Carousel Image" Item="<%# Container.DataItem %>" runat="server" />
<h1><sc:Text Field="Carousel Text" Item="<%# Container.DataItem %>" runat="server"/></h1>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `sc:Image` and `sc:Text` in the repeater but you need to bind it to the list of items that are selected in the multilist field. A multilist field will have a (piped) list of guids as raw value, and you can get the items with the Sitecore API if you cast the field to a `MultilistField`:

```
var multilistfield = (MultilistField)field;
var items = multilistfield.GetItems();
repeater.DataSource = items;
```